# Mozilla Firefox middle mouse button does not work

Tags: firefox, mouse, tabs

I use Mozilla Firefox 55.0.2, Ubuntu 17.04. Earlier, I used middle mouse button for opening a link in a new tab. However, in this version, it does not work.
After reading older questions, I checked `about:config`, and:

- `browser.tabs.opentabfor.middleclick` and `middlemouse.contentLoadURL` are`true`
- `middlemouse.openNewWindow`, `middlemouse.paste` and `middlemouse.scrollbarPosition` are `false`

The only extensions I use are AdBlock Plus 2.9.1 and Ubuntu Modifications 3.4.

Also, I would like to use middleclick scrolling.

Comment: For  middleclick scrolling go to **Preferences** ➜ **Advanced** ➜ check **Use autoscrolling**

Comment: Also try changing `middlemouse.contentLoadURL` to `false`

Comment: I did both and nothing changed

Comment: Have you restarted Firefox after making changes?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: Try changing all of `middlemouse.openNewWindow`, `middlemouse.paste` and `middlemouse.scrollbarPosition` to `true`.

Comment: Does not work either

Comment: I also refreshed firefox, removing all extensions, and didn't solve the problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turned out that the middle button of my mouse has been broken :(

The correct settings for the desired function are (using @pomsky's comments):

`middlemouse.contentLoadURL=false`

`middlemouse.openNewWindow=true`

`middlemouse.paste=true`

`middlemouse.scrollbarPosition=true`

For middleclick scrolling I set

`general.autoScroll=true`